# ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC - how to exclude some folders from View Compilation?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Here's the scenario - I use this code https://iamrufio.com/2017/09/08/rendering-emails-with-razorviewengine-in-net-core-2-0/ (thanks to author) to render views to string (for emails). But when you publish the project all views get compiled, so I loose my Views/Emails/[templates]. How can I exclude some folders from being compiled (and not deployed) when publishing?

I found this https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation and used `MvcRazorExcludeViewFilesFromPublish set to false` and it worked. But now I have all my Views deployed (are they still precompiled I wonder?). Not a big deal but I'd have only some of them deployed.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this, its working for me.

- Leave MvcRazorCompileOnPublish to true (default).
- Exclude your folder *templates* folder with views which should not be
  precompiled from project. You can do this with **Exclude From
  Project** context menu options, or with this code in *.csproj* file:

> ```
> <ItemGroup>
>     <Compile Remove="Views\Emails\templates\**" />
>     <Content Remove="Views\Emails\templates\**" />
>     <EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\Emails\templates\**" />
>     <None Remove="Views\Emails\templates\**" />
> </ItemGroup>
> ```

- If you now publish project, *.PrecompiledViews.dll* is created, but
  without views in templates folder.
- You can manualy (or with custom task) copy *templates* folder to publish root directory.
- Now views is find in this external folder, but you probably endup with error:

> Cannot find compilation library location for package
>   'Microsoft.Win32.Registry'

To correct this, you must to publish folder add **refs**
   subfolder with some runtime assemblies. This **refs** folder is normaly created if you do publish project with **MvcRazorCompileOnPublish** set to **false**. So you must one time do publish without precompilation to another folder and copy this refs subfolder from there.

Comment: oh, thanks man. I'll give it a try within days. Need to finish other stuff first (you know how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add this in your `.csproj` file?

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="Views\DoNotPublishThisFolder\**">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>

  <Content Update="some-file-to-not-publish.xxx">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Otherwise, you could select the folder or file via the Visual Studio GUI by right-clicking and selecting properties and select **"Do not copy"**

[image]

Comment: @TonyBasallo -- I just added more details to the answer