# In asp.net core 2, is there a way to deploy uncompiled .cshtml files?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-2.0, webdeploy

I am using RazorLight to render razor templates (.cshtml files) to strings, and then I use those in emails.

This works fine in development, but upon deployment (via WebDeploy to Azure App Services), all the .cshtml files are compiled down to [Project].PrecompiledViews.dll so I can't access the raw .cshtml... There are other ways to approach this, such as storing the template in a database or blob storage, but it is convenient to simply publish the templates along with my project. Making them embedded resources might be an option, although that feels a little ugly.

I have tried copying them into my wwwroot folder, marking them as Copy Always, and I've been researching this for a few hours. No luck so far. Is there any way to make this work, perhaps at the .csproj level?

Comment: can you rename them with a .html extension (or maybe even better something else that a browser wouldn't try to render, if someone accessed the URL directly) so the build engine doesn't try to compile them? I don't know the Razorlight tool but would it still be able to process them if they're still a Razor template, but just with a different extension? I would hope it wouldn't care.

Comment: @ADyson That may be an option, it just breaks the IDE, since it recognizes razor syntax based on that extension.

Comment: You could exclude a subfolder from compilation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978823/asp-net-core-2-0-mvc-how-to-exclude-some-folders-from-view-compilation

Comment: It occurs to me that the IDE can probably be configured to provide intellisense etc on other file extensions

Comment: @ADyson Hmm that is true, I could probably make it .razor or something. Little janky, but worth a try!

Comment: @CodeCaster I am actually sitting here trying to get that to work right now. Currently getting HTTP Error 502.5, still fiddling with it though.

Comment: @CodeCaster No luck with that, sadly. I think I can prevent compilation, but I can't force it to actually deploy .cshtml files.

Comment: @ADyson I think I might use gulp to copy my .cshtml files to wwwroot/emailTemplates and change the extension :)

Comment: @ADyson That doesn't work either, RazorLight adds .cshtml to the end... I am going to do a pull request. There has to be an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is possible to deploy the raw CHTML files as in the earlier versions of .Net Core.
We have to set the below property to false in csproj file:

```
            MvcRazorCompileOnPublish
```

Refer this location for more information: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-2.1