# Uncompiled partial view doesn't inherit from ViewImports

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I moved a part of a view into a partial view.

---

_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using AsonCore.Helpers
@using AsonCore.Models
@namespace AsonCore.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Application.cshtml

```
@page
@model ApplicationModel

<partial name="/Pages/Partial/_ApplicationPartial.cshtml" />
```

_ApplicationPartial.cshtml

```
@model ApplicationModel
<section class="content application">
    <div>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label asp-for='email.Firstname'>FORNAVN</label>
                <input asp-for='email.Firstname' required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label asp-for="email.Lastname">ETTERNAVN</label>
                <input asp-for="email.Lastname" required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
            </div>
        </form>
        <partial name="/Pages/Shared/_FormScript.cshtml" />
    </div>
</section>
```

_Project.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <RootNamespace>AsonCore</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Pages\Partial\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Pages\Partial\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

---

At build the partial views are removed from the compiled *views.dll* to enable dynamic updates of their content, and when I did, what initially were inherited from `_ViewImports.cshtml` stopped.

By adding `@namespace AsonCore.Pages` to the partial view it picked up the `Model`, but then I noticed, after deploying to server (it works in VS2019 though), that "TagHelpers" stopped working.

Also adding `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` to the view fixed that, but my question is, is this how it need/should be done?

Or is there any other way to prevent specific views from being compiled, where the inheritance from "ViewImports" is preserved?

Answer (score 2):

I post this self-answer as a temporary workaround (still hope for one though, that will explain what goes on, and where to find it in official resources/docs).

---

It appears it is no more complicated than for a compiled partial view, it uses the compiled `_ViewImports.cshtml`, and for any uncompiled it needs a copy of the `_ViewImports.cshtml` in its default location, the `Pages\` folder.

In my case something like this

```
\Pages\Partial\
  _Application.cshtml

\Pages\
  _ViewImports.cshtml

\
  AsonCore.Views.dll
```

---

It also turns out, that one can take any other compiled main view file (which weren't removed on publish, as I did with the partial view), copy it to the `Pages\` folder, edit it if one want to, and it will reload and override the compiled one, that resides in the *views.dll*

---

The above alone will render in an exception though (when trying to execute uncompiled views at runtime), but with help from this answer it works, which says:

> To correct this, you must to publish folder add **refs** subfolder with
>   some runtime assemblies. This **refs** folder is normaly created if you do
>   publish project with `MvcRazorCompileOnPublish` set to `false`. So you
>   must one time do publish without precompilation to another folder and
>   copy this **refs** subfolder from there.

- [ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC - how to exclude some folders from View Compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978823/asp-net-core-2-0-mvc-how-to-exclude-some-folders-from-view-compilation/47872307#47872307)

*Note, there might be some other way than to use this **refs** folder in Core 2.2, and if someone know, please, feel free to edit my answer with that*

---

**Edit - ASP.NET Core 3.1**

When it comes to the `refs` folder using 3.1, one just do this to get the *runtime files* copied when publish:

In `startup` class

```
services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

In `.csproj` file

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.1.4" />
```

Comment: FYI, you can set `CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory` to `true` in the .csproj file instead of setting up rules to copy the files manually, etc. The MSBuild properties are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-2.2#properties).